# having problem loading url from the views and url in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I am building a webpage from a custom bootstrap template available freely in GitHub. I have tried to connect Django to the back end. I am facing problem using urls and views. I have mentioned perfectly but i am getting page not found.

urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homepage, name='homepage'),
    path('publications', views.publications, name='publications'),
    path('alumni', views.alumni, name='alumni'),
    path('contact', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('joinus', views.joinus, name='joinus'),
    path('phdstudents', views.phdstudents, name='phdstudents'),
    path('pi', views.pi, name='pi'),
    path('project1', views.project1, name='project1'),
    path('research', views.research, name='research'),
    path('researchers',views.researchers, name='researchers'),
    path('shiladit', views.shiladit, name='shiladit'),
    path('students', views.students, name='students'),
    path('team', views.students, name='team'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def homepage(request):
    return render(request, 'lab/index.html')
def publications(request):
    return render(request, 'lab/publications.html')
def alumni(request):
    return render(request, 'lab/alumni.html')
def contact(request):
    return render(request, 'lab/contact.html')
def joinus(request):
    return render(request, 'joinus.html')
def phdstudents(request):
    return render(request, 'phd_students.html')
def pi(request):
    return render(request, 'lab/pi.html')
def project1(request):
    return render(request, 'lab/project1.html')
def publications(request):
    return render(request, 'lab/publications.html')
def research(request):
    return render(request, 'lab/research.html')
def researchers(request):
    return render(request, 'researchers.html')
```

when i click on the navbar to redirect the page i am getting error. but when i give the url it is loading how to rectify this.
[image]

[image]

Comment: The URL you want is `http://127.0.01:8000/research` (without `/index.html`), that's what's in your `urls.py`. How is the navbar template generating the links?

Comment: Have you checked `http://127.0.01:8000/lab/research.html` ?

Comment: Thanks for poiting out @IainShelvington I have not removed `.html` in navbar template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Remove :** http://127.0.01:8000/research.html
- **Try This :** http://127.0.01:8000/research

*In template(Html):*

- **Remove**

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="research.html">Research</a></li>
</ul>
```

- **Try This :**

```html
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/research/">Research</a></li>
    </ul>
```